# BLOTTER.JS why does the first loading of my index.html default to serif font instead of my custom font 'auth'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I first load index.html the blotter text defaults to serif. when I refresh it once it switches to my custom 'auth' font and stays as that font with each subsequent refresh

```
<div id="title"></div>
```

my css

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    src: url(helvetica.ttf);
    
    font-family: 'auth';
    src: url(auth.otf);
}
```

javascript

```
var text = new Blotter.Text("~DAISY CHAIN~", {
  family : "auth",
  size : 150,
  fill : "#000000",
    paddingLeft : 120,
    paddingRight :120
});

text.needsUpdate = true;

var material = new Blotter.LiquidDistortMaterial();
material.uniforms.uSpeed.value = 0.3;
material.uniforms.uVolatility.value = .1;
material.uniforms.uSeed.value = .10;



var blotter = new Blotter(material, {
  texts : text

});

var elem = document.getElementById("title");
var scope = blotter.forText(text);

scope.appendTo(elem);

document.onmousemove = function distort(){
    material.uniforms.uVolatility.value = (event.clientY * .0006);;
}
```

Comment: Probably because the font has not finished loading yet the first time …?

Comment: did u figure it out? i cannot find any info about this anywhere

Comment: @oldboy I did! I followed the instructions in this post https://github.com/bradley/Blotter/issues/37 it's worked perfect so far.

Comment: i realized the issue was that the font was loading after the blotter instance was initiated :( but i have encountered a new issue whereby, unless you use a very dark color for either the text or background, the rendered text sometimes shows black marks along the outline of the characters. have you noticed this? if so, have you been able to fix it?